# IAsyncResult object

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I get this error when i make a while loop for asynch Method call

Error>>the IAsyncResult object provided does not match this delegate

```
while(true)
{
  ..........
  Delegate =new MethodInvoker(UploadProcedureCall);
  callback=new AsyncCallback(EndInvoke);
  tag=Delegate.BeginInvoke(Params,obj,callback,null);
  Delegate.EndInvoke(tag);
}
```

Any Help?

Comment: Plus, why are you using async here when you're just going to block on the `EndInvoke` call one line later?

Comment: block what?
more details please

Comment: I cannot figure out your context. What type is the `Delegate`?The usual `System.Delegate`?

Comment: Delegate is type of methodinvoker __
Methodinvoker is type of System.Delegate __
callback is type of AsyncCallback __
tag is type of IAsyncResult  __
all is defined outside the while loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is because of static members.